# JQuery AutoComplete, manually select first item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jQueryUI autocomplete, and I want that when I get the focus on the input field, a list appears and the first element of the list was selected coinciding with the text. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for the replies.

My html:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
    <input id="tags"/>
</div>
```

My javascript:

```
var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"];

$("#tags").val("ja");
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    autoFocus: true,
}).on( "focusin", function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", $(this).val());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wx5a1q5k/3/

thanks

please someone help

Answer (score 0):

It is because that you have not set `minLength` property, set `minLength: 0` in your autocomplete plugin.

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
     source: availableTags,
     autoFocus: true,
     minLength: 0
})
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qk0vz4a/).

Comment: This does not work. Because the first element of the list is not selected

Comment: @timtoady I have updated the code. Hope that will work for u.

Comment: This also does not work. If "ja" is entered in the field and the input gets focus. Then the first element of the list is not selected